# transfinite numbers and the Skolem "paradox"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Q** does the Lowenheim-Skolem argument imply that there is a countable model of a proper class?

Comment: The title, by the way, has absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. If that was true, since $V$, the universe of sets, satisfies all the axioms of $\sf ZFC$ this would mean that there is a countable model of $\sf ZFC$ in $V$. In particular, it would mean that every universe of $\sf ZFC$ would think that $\sf ZFC$ is consistent.

That, in turn, means that $\sf ZFC$ can prove its own consistency. And this is impossible due to Godel's incompleteness theorems.